# Python causing server error when trying to save new JSON file

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json, raspberry-pi

I'm new to Python, so let me know if there's any glaring mistakes.

I've created a simple webpage that uses Ajax, reads the server's XML response, and then displays it on a page.  I'm using a python script to send the XML response, which it's building from a JSON file, and it's working perfectly.

But my problem occurs when I add some code to my Python script that modifies my JSON prior to sending the XML response.

Here is the code that causes the problem:

```
with open("../../../var/www/data.json", "r+") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    data[0]["A"] = "2"
    jsonFile.seek(0)  # rewind
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data))
    jsonFile.truncate()
```

When this code is put into my python file, I get this error in my browser console when my Ajax sends the POST request: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

But the funny thing is, even though it prevents my server from responding properly, it does correctly update my JSON file.

Why does writing to my JSON file cause my server to not respond to my POST request?

Here is my Javascript function which sends the post request:

```
function sendAjax(){
    sendingAjax = true;

    console.log("sending ajax...");

    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', "/cgi-bin/xmlTest.py", true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4 && self.xmlHttpReq.status == 200) {
             if (self.xmlHttpReq.responseXML != null) {
                console.log("server responded with 4!");
                document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = self.xmlHttpReq.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('data')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                sendingAjax = false;
            }
        }
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send();

}
```

And here is the Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import cgitb
import json



#this worked to open the json file, rewrite it, and then open it again for reading but it needs to be commented out for server to respond properly
with open("../../../var/www/data.json", "r+") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    data[0]["A"] = "2"
    jsonFile.seek(0)  # rewind
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data))
    jsonFile.truncate()

newJsonFile = open("../../../var/www/data.json", "r")
newData = json.load(newJsonFile)
newJsonFile.close()

cgitb.enable()


print "Content-Type: text/xml"     
print # blank line, end of headers
print "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><inputs><data>"+newData[0]["A"]+"</data></inputs>"
```

Any idea why that bit of code causes my server to send the 500 error code?

P.S. - I'm using a Raspberyy Pi 2 as my server.

Comment: So, without file modification, it works fine? I mean, if you get rid of `with...` and keep everything else identical.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: @khajvah - yes, if i delete the with everything works fine.  I believe raspberry pi comes with version 2 and 3 installed, but I'm not sure which vesion is being used on it's Apache server.  Is there a way to check?

Comment: If the code works without the with statement, then you are using python2, as print statements are not valid python3 prints. I am not sure how apache works with python. Your problem seems weird. The with statement has no problems but it is what causes the problem as you claim. This seems to be an apache issue

Comment: Try to put `cgitb.enable(display=0, logdir="/path/to/logdir")` before the `with` line and see the error massage

Comment: Found my problem, but not sure how to enable write permission: <type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '../../../var/www/data.json'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we have found the bug together in the comments section. RP is a linux system I think so permission errors can be resolved with `chmod`. Log in in the shell as the user that owns the apache process and change the permission **OR** just do it in a simpler way: `cd` to `/www/` directory and run the following command:

```
cd /var/www
sudo chmod a+w data.json
```

Note that this will give writing permission to **every** user in your system.